# What notes do the different colors correspond with?

Tags: guitar-hero

The title really says it all. I can't find anything about it on the Internet (then again, I never find anything), but it's obvious that songs can't be played with 5 notes. I still think there must be some kind of system behind it...

Comment: I sincerely doubt they have matches to actual notes.

Comment: Because guitars only have 5 notes....

Comment: Related: https://www.chordbuddy.com/  You can play real songs with color coded buttons!  Like guitar hero IRL...

Answer (score 27):

There are no notes that the colours match with. They are simply used to denote increase or decrease in pitch, and "chords" when used together.

Comment: Out of interest, does that mean 2 different songs can play a slightly different sound for the same colour?

Comment: @CamelCase: You often see even the _same song_ assigning different sounds to the same colour, example: https://youtu.be/cHRfbiwdheg?t=145
(Doesn't even seem to just be higher octaves of the same notes - as I say in my answer, there is no notable correlation between note and colour)

Comment: @CamelCase yes, you may find that some songs have more than 5 notes.

Answer (score 16):

As Jeeva said, there's no real parallel.

On a real guitar, you have six strings each with 20+ frets, which are difficult to replicate exactly without making the game needlessly complex. The key to the game is its simplicity while still feeling like you're making music, so if you had a button for each fret on each string, it'd defeat the purpose. Not to mention that there are only 5 buttons despite there being 7 notes in a major scale, which means buttons would need to be mapped to multiple notes, which would particularly make chords end up strangely but would also mean certain buttons get pressed much more often.

But that's not as important to developers (or players) as capturing the *feeling* of playing. If you've played guitar at all, you know that as you finger the frets toward the base of the instrument (the wider part where you strum with your other hand), the pitch gets higher. So, what the designers decided would best imitate the *feeling* of being a rock star is having the player's fingering moved toward the buttons nearer to the base of the guitar, not based on mapping notes to them, but based on each phrase of a song being played, and where that phrase hits its highest notes. Those notes are usually mapped to either the fourth or fifth buttons, and pretty much everything else is organized around that.

Comment: I don’t know if I buy “needlessly complex” – you’d just be that much closer to playing an actual guitar at that point. Having the notes flying towards you and getting real-time feedback might be a good way to learn guitar, even (though you’d also want real strings and strumming).

Comment: @KRyan There's a game like that. RockSmith (2014) is similar to Guitar Hero, but played with a real electric guitar. It's pretty fun.

Comment: @KRyan "Needless" is debatable I suppose, but I think the game would have been worse off if it didn't simplify the mechanics as much as it did. If people wanted to play guitar they would play guitar. A game which imitated guitar playing to a T would need to be a teaching game or it wouldn't have much of an audience. The point of rock band and guitar hero is that you don't have to know how the guitar works to enjoy playing and get that rock star feeling.

Comment: @AverageUnknown: Ironically, I've found such those games on older systems with a CRT television preferable to playing them on a more modern system, since an older system could play notes in response to the player actions and have them be in time with the music, but on newer systems the only way a player's note will sound in time with the rest of the music will be if the system outputs the sound of the player hitting the note in advance of when the player is actually supposed to hit it, making it impossible for a player to hear if the note was played a smidgen early or late.

Comment: Rock Band 3 has a guitar controller with 120 buttons on it, and strings to pluck. :) It also supports real guitar through a USB adapter.

Comment: There are a few songs (or parts of songs) that I know how to play on an actual guitar, that are included in a Guitar Hero and/or Rock Band game, and I have found that for those songs, my muscle memory from the real guitar translates quite well into playing on the controller. For instance, a song that involves stepping through 3 frets on one string and then the same 3 frets on another string is represented in the games in that same way, even though the notes are continually climbing in pitch for that series (which by a simpler explanation would tend to step through all five buttons).

Comment: @supercat - some modern TVs and/or sound systems have "gaming modes" that reduce latency, and all major rhythm games have a latency calibration feature to dial in the timing perfectly.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Rhythm games do indeed have latency calibration, but all they can do is adjust when they should expect your response.  If the screen has 50ms of lag (1.5 frames) even in gaming mode, a game must either have audio play 50ms late when the human is playing precisely in time, or else play audio before the human is expected to play it.  Some older CRT-based game machines had 17ms *worst-case* latency, with best-case latency being below a millisecond (if the player's character was near the top of the screen, and the player hit a button during vertical retrace, the effects...

Comment: ...could sometimes be registered on the immediate next frame).  I'm not sure what would be required from a hardware perspective to make a flat panel update its content from top to bottom as pixels came in, but modern flat panels almost never do.

Comment: And they do, in fact, start playing a note before the human is expected to trigger it, cutting it off abruptly if the input doesn't come.

Comment: -1 because this seems more like a discussion on comparison between RL guitar and controller guitar. You answer the why (through self admited speculation), without why being asked. Also, this is not the place for discussion, guys. If you want to talk about the game, take it to the chat

Comment: @Timelord64 I felt that going into more detail was the most reasonable way to add an answer that didn't just copy Jeeva's. Comparing the two was my attempt to not just say there was no parallel, but show why and how it would be difficult to create a meaningful and accessible parallel with the limited number of buttons Guitar Hero uses.

Comment: @AverageUnknown, whats important to remember is that this is just your opinion. While it makes sense, explaining why goes into developer intent. It also pushes towards disussion, as seen above. Both have no place in arqade, and generally promote downvoting and deletion.

Comment: I find putting an abridged version at the top, in a TLDR format, helps negate this. In this instance, you have been most informative to the layman. But promotion of discussion, and opinion in itself, is something youd be best staying away from.

Answer (score 5):

The colors are just to help you correlate what feat button you are suppose to hit. As others pointed out typically the pitch gets higher on the higher frets, but the whole color coding/fret layout is to simplify the act of sight reading on guitar which it conveys the simple idea while being very accessible to people who don't play guitar.

Typically you'll shift your fingers up and down the neck to play at different positions, but once you are there you'll typically say there and hit note across the frets at the position you are at hence why there are 5 frets.

When you are actually playing a song you take advantage of the different positions to minimize movement, but you still need to hit the right notes at the right time which the fret scroll is acting as in a clever way.

For example for *Sweet Child of Mine* (in Guitar Hero 3) on a real guitar you would see either the sheet music:

[image]

Or the tabs:

[image]

On guitar hero instead you see this:

[image]

Seeing fret numbers would not be as intuitive as the colors for an obvious reason as the colors pop more especially at higher speeds.